# Auto suggest, Azure Webapp & .Net core WebAPI iMemoryCache

Tags: azure, caching, .net-core, azure-web-app-service, webapi

Tech Stack

- Azure WebApp
- .Net core 2.1 WebApi

We have around 4k reference data which is used during auto suggest lookup, so in this i was wondering whether i should cache this data on WebApp or should always get it from database / 3rd party API.

I know i can use RedisCache to solve this issue, but i would like to know how Azure WebApp works when it comes to caching, it will have memory pressure? When? Yes then scale-up is the only solution?

We are using IMemoryCache in .net Core to store reference data and it expires on daily basis or when Azure WebApp is restarted (So 1st user will get delay till it gets all data in cache).

Data size is in range of 500KB - 1MB & sometimes goes till 3MB+.

What is the best approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**iMemoryCache is not suggested when using WebApps** because it is tightly bound to your application instance, so if you try to scale out your app (in case of load surges during the day) your caching mechanism will be broken.

- RedisCache is pretty much a dictionary, key-value pairs.
- It is **very fast on look-ups but it could be very slow** in some other operations like a GetAllKeys when it has to run through the whole cache. That will bring your cache server to its knees, so it needs to be handled carefully.
- It will not put any significant pressure in the memory consumption of your app, you only need to have a static client. The rest is handled by the redis server.

If you plan to scale up your application (give more RAM and CPU resources to your one running instance) the iMemory cache is probably fine.

If you plan to scale out (create multiple instances of your application), that is strongly suggested for all stateless applications, then RedisCache (or any other distributed cache) is an one way for you if you need a caching mechanism.

Value and key max size is 512MB so you are on the safe side regarding value data size.

**Attention**

Be sure to use the Connection multiplexer as it is suggested in the official [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-cache-for-redis/cache-dotnet-how-to-use-azure-redis-cache) because it automatically re-establishes the connection in case it is lost. That was a bug earlier, when redis cache server was going into maintenance your calls where redirected to the fail over instance but the connection was failing, so you needed to restart your application.

Comment: Hello Stelios, Thanks for your reply. in case of scale out also & without sticky session, if we talk about reference data, if cache is not in given cache, it will again take it from DB and keep it in cache, right ? so only problem is that all instances can have different version of cache data (in this case this, it will not as new data will be part of deployment process which requires restart of webapp)

Comment: Hi @ManishJoisar, the reason what you just described is a bad practice is not because you have 2 (or more) caches with different data, it is mainly that you need to query your database twice, possibly for the same entry (you do not use sticky sessions). By using a cache you usually try to minimize db calls because they are bottlenecks in an application.

Comment: This documentation article explains that 'Azure Web apps use Application Request Routing (ARR) to route all subsequent requests to the same server.'  (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/memory?view=aspnetcore-3.1#caching-basics)
Isn't it then implying that also subsequent requests will hit the same app service instance?